# Angularjs function not working inside iframe

Tags: html, angularjs, function, iframe

Is there any way to use angularJS functions on an iframe?(not even basic true or false) 
I have tried numerous times, but iframe acts as an independent body.
Please drop me any suggestions you may have to solve this problem?

Comment: See this image for reference: https://ibb.co/XxYrMCr

Answer (score 0):

**NO WAY**

is used for calling another webpage into your webpage.
there is no relation between your webpage and insdie iframe page.

Comment: i just want to close a popup by clicking on that iframe,in that very page

Comment: popup is inside iframe or out side iframe ?

Comment: it is outside iframe

Comment: see this please: https://ibb.co/XxYrMCr
1 is dropdown and 2 is iframe area